# Inequality for a power function

Tags: inequality

Can anyone tell me under what conditions the following is correct??

Given two real variables $x$ and $y$,

\begin{equation}
(y-x)^b \le y^b - x^b
\end{equation}

where y > x and $0\le b \le 1$.

Thanks

Comment: $x\geq0$ I guess...well there are some obvious cases: in the case $b=1$ it always works, in the case $b=0$ it never works

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^b$ and check the convexity or (concavity).

Answer (score 1):

The opposite is mostly true:

As pointed out by user190080, we need to have $x>0$ in order to remain in the set of real numbers. With the substitution $y=z+x, \space x+z>x\iff z>0$, the inequality is equivalent to:
$$
x^b+z^b≤(x+z)^b
$$
For $0≤b≤1$ and $x,z>0$.

But in  fact, we can show that:
$$
x^b+z^b≥(x+z)^b
$$
With equality only if $b=1$:

As the inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $x+z=1$. We then have $0<x,z<1$ and therefore:
$$
x≤x^b,\space z≤z^b \implies 1=x+z≤x^b+z^b
$$
Which proves the inequality.

So your inequality can only be true if $b=1$ or if $b≠0$ and $x=0$.

Note:

If you are not used to the concept of homogeneity, here is an explanation:

We can divide the inequality by $(x+z)^b$ which leaves:
$$
\left(\frac{x}{x+z}\right)^b+\left(\frac{z}{x+z}\right)^b≥1
$$
If we substitute $\frac{x}{x+z}=a$ and $\frac{z}{x+z}=c$ respectively, it remains to prove that for $a+c=1$ we have $a^b+c^b≥1$ which is the same as above with the shortcut.

Comment: Your claim $$ x^b+z^b≥(x+z)^b$$ seems strange, since for positive x and z it is not true.

Comment: I am retracting my comment.